# Show a completely black screen in an app

Tags: iphone, ios

My app shows a full-screen UIView, which is black, opaque, alpha=1. This should result in a black screen, right? Well, it does, but only sort of. It looks black in normal light, but when I go into a dark room, I can see that the screen glows a little. When I lock the phone, then the screen goes completely dark.

I'd like the screen to be completely dark with my app running in the foreground.

I realize it might not be possible to turn off the screen backlight from within an app, but is there anything I can do to achieve what I want?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: this totally worked, thank you! If you make this an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [brightness](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScreen/brightness) property on UIScreen allows you to control the iOS device's backlight intensity.